# Magento Hosting - Have I reached the max speed on shared?

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting

I'm not sure if this question is allowed according to the question guide.
However I have got a Magento store with bout 620 products (planning to reach 1.5k-2k) on a shared hosting on h*stga*** since the cost of dedicated server is not affordable, I have tried to reduce the load time: `2.4` seconds and `0.889` for fisrt byte.
I have:

- Disabled etag
- Enabled gzip
- Added future header
- Reduced the number of cookies for static content served from CDN
- CDN for css, media and js
- Fooman Speedster Advanced
- Full Page Cache plugin
- Reduced CSS code size
- Compiliant Mode On

I wonder if it the maximum speed I can reach with a shared hosting plan or not? I'm not talking about a 10-20 milliseconds, but 80 millisecond 1 second and about 300ms for first byte.
My store is based in italy and sells only here and the server is placed in USA (I think Austin).
 I have tought about moving the server to another host and looking online I have read good review about Sit*gr**nd, beacuse if I don't get it wrong it offers a cache system(varnish, memcached,..) also on shared hosting, plus ithas got server also in europe, so considering the moving cost and potencial problems (new dns,etc...), will I get a noticiable benefit?

Comment: @Serpyre 1% in hosting isn't possible at this moment, I'm still working on SEO and ways to reduce the end-user extra cost(such as shipping), the site receives about 30-40 hit per day and the receive about 3-4 orders per month with a revenue of 15-20$ each, so a VPS that is about 50/90$ per month isn't an affordable option, as far as I have understood it's better to stay on the current server and wait untill the site has got enough traffic/revenue to move to a VPS plan, is it correct?

Comment: @Serpyre Sorry, as a non native english speaker I have got some problems to get this phrase:"The only way to fast track it is to loss lead better hosting", could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: @Serpyre Basically you are says: "keep your current plan, solve your conversion rate problem as soon as possible and then move to VPS the first time you can", is it correct? (Also I'm on Hostgator)

Comment: @Serpyre have you got any suggestion about a decent magento hosting company(even better if it located in europe)?

Comment: @Serpyre Last question about nexcess: I see that they have got shared and dedicated, the last one isn't affordable, about the shared:SIP 200 with 13 accounts is fine? or talking in general which solution should I choose?

Answer (score 2):

The best performance you can achieve with a particular setup depends on a great many things, but one thing is for sure - running Magento under shared hosting is not a great idea.  It really is just too much of a heavy application for that and while you may be able to get it running in a fairly acceptable fashion, it's very unlikely to stay that way when you start getting traffic to the site.

Also because you will only have access to very minimal resources, you will find that you very soon exhaust available resources and start seeing exceptions thrown on the frontend and backend as the PHP's memory requirements outstript the available resources.

You don't need to go for a dedicated server, but you should at least be using a VPS hosting package.  They are significantly cheaper than a dedicated server and can still be configured with easily enough resources to run a Magento store well as long as you are not seeing heavy traffic.

Bear in mind that with FPC, there are always going to be parts of the store which will never be cached like the cart and checkout pages so you need to make sure you are happy with the performance of the store without caching enabled first.  Customers are likely to soon find somewhere else to buy from if the site becomes suddenly slow when trying to checkout.  With the right hosting and the right caching you can expect to easily achieve sub 100ms HTML generation times for cached pages.  You may also be interested to try our [performance profiler](http://store.husseycoding.co.uk/profiler) to get some clear simple advice on improving the performance of your store.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added some information under the question in a response, the load time of the cart and the checkout(12 products) is in the order of 2 seconds. Considerring the information of the answer under the question, do you think that is better to stay on the current host/plan or try to move to the other server still on shared but with a memcached system? Later I will try to completely disable the FPC and do some tests

Comment: Unfortunately shared hosting just doesn't have the raw power to run Magento.  You are very likely to start seeing the site go to the exception error page for requests on a fairly regular basis if you continue to run the store under shared hosting.  If you are not able to justify the cost of even a basic VPS hosting package Magento probably isn't the right platform for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you, about VPS: which is a good spec? I mean: CPU 2 Cores RAM 2 GB Disk Space 120 GB Bandwidth 1.5 TB for 90$/mo, is it good(price/spec)?

Comment: For the kind of traffic you are getting you can probably get away with a single core and 1GB, but preferably 2GB of RAM.  Don't worry too much about disk space or bandwidth, what comes with a package of that size will be fine for your current needs I think.  They are UK based, but something [BigV](https://www.bigv.io/) is pretty good value.  I'm sure there is an equivalent more geographically local to you.